# Return Pass/Fail based on 3 consecutive passes; ignore blanks

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

<Edited to correct my error about "RowA", whoops!>

I need to make a pass/fail sheet that returns a value in A1 based on the consecutive values in Row1. For example, if B1,C1,D1 are pass, A1=pass. But if B1, C1 are pass and D1 is fail, A1=Fail. Which I know how to do using IFs. BUT the thing I'm struggling with is that I need it to continue searching until it finds 3 consecutive passes or otherwise returns a fail.

So: B1=fail, C1=Pass, D1=Pass, E1=blank, F1=Pass needs to return a Pass for A1. There are no limits to how many attempts will be made to get 3 consecutive passes, but there will certainly be gaps in the days the tests are done.

I would prefer to do this with formulas, but I can make it a macro if there's no other way.

Comment: There is no row A. Do you mean Column A or Row 1?

Comment: Try using this formula in cell A1`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("PassPassPass",TEXTJOIN("",,$A$2:$A$6))),"Pass","Fail")` this should give you the consecutive passes.

Comment: Could you confirm once are you looking for consecutive passes or the 3 continuous passes?

Comment: Ike, yes, I meant Row1, sorry. So A1 would actually be searching thru all of Row 1's columns for 3 consecutive passes before it returns a pass indication. I apologize for the error! I edited the post to reflect what I should've written.

Comment: Mayukh Bhattacharya, that worked beautifully!!!! THANK YOU!!!

Comment: @RiskyFish ah okay I just checked your comment, glad it worked for you & thanks for sharing the feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this formula, this shall find the consecutive `Pass` values as expected,

• Formula used in cell **A1**

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("PassPassPass",TEXTJOIN("",,$A$2:$A$6))),"Pass","Fail")
```

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]